# handling 404 status in findById method

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, mongoose

I am creating RESTful API on node.js (express.js + mongoose).
I have mongoose model which has _id and title.

When I handle GET request to find specific object by _id, I use findById method and I want to know how to handle if the requested id was wrong. In other words, the question is "how to handle 404 status for findById method".

I have tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
Blog.findById(id)
    .select("_id title")
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
        if (result) {
            res.status(200).json({
                article: result
            });
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Article was not found'
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
```

Comment: What was the error? Also what is the `result` in your first `.then`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.findById` in mongoose will return null when no object matches the criteria, so you can simply put an if clause inside `.then()` before all code

```
.then(result => {
  if(!result) return res.status(404).send('No result found');
  // rest of your code here
```

And that will send a 404 to client.